# What is "Attempt to lookup host entry for bad IP address" error?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, web-services, gnu

Check this error and please help me.

```
2009-07-24 15:58:34.209 LBS[2636] Host 'staging.common.virtualearth.net' not found using 'gethostbyname()' - perhaps the hostname is wrong or networking is not set up on your machine
2009-07-24 15:58:34.209 LBS[2636] Attempt to lookup host entry for bad IP address (staging.common.virtualearth.net)
NOTE: you should run 'diskperf -y' to enable the disk statistics
```

I am running the objC codes for hitting a webservice on GNU for Windows.

Why is this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line says it can't find the IP address off the DNS servers.

The second is some kind of fallback with an incredibly cryptic error. Looks like it's trying reverse DNS using hostname as the IP address (hence bad IP address) or ARP resolution using hostname as IP address.

Basically fix the DNS to that host and both will be solved.